# PHP variable as hyperlink

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, isset

I'm trying to set the php variables linked to one of my page in the folder, **`index.html`**. However, I am getting an error of `Name&lang=en">` Any help?

```
if (isset($result_array)) {
    foreach ($result_array as $result) {
        $name = preg_replace("/" . $search . "/i", "<b class='high'>" . $search . "</b>", $result['Name']);
        $url = '<a href="index.html">' . urlencode($result['Name']) . '&lang=en';
        $out = str_replace('nameS', $name, $html);
        $out = str_replace('urlS', $url, $out);
        $_SESSION[$search] = $result['Name'];
        echo($out);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is your expected url?

Comment: index.html. But i want to display the result's name and hyperlink it to index.html

Comment: `$url = '<a href="index.html">'.urlencode($result['Name']).'&lang=en'.'</a>';` try this

Comment: or `$url = '<a href="index.html">'.urlencode($result['Name'].'&lang=en').'</a>';` try this

Comment: neither any of it work :(

Comment: Actually it's unclear what you really want?

Comment: this:-`$url = '<a href="index.html">'.$result['Name'].'</a>';` will give you something like `<a href="index.html">Rohan</a>`